# Shrink encrypted home partition

Tags: encryption, gparted, partitioning, btrfs

My current partition setup looks like this

`$ sudo df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        1.6G  2.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p1_crypt   96G   24G   71G  26% /
/dev/nvme0n1p3               1.3G  263M  920M  23% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p2               1.5G   40M  1.4G   3% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p4_crypt  379G  307G   73G  81% /home`

I want to shrink my encrypted home partition by 50Gb and make it as a new partition to install windows

I tried Gparted and googled for the solution that doesn't involve loss of data, but no luck

Please suggest a way without data loss

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) from Ubuntu Help, is very well explained and no data loss is involved. You said you tried Gparted, please note that in order to "play" with partitions you might be using a Live version of Ubuntu, as Ubuntu won't let you shrink any partitions from the system which is being used. Therefore you are going to need the USB you used for installing Ubuntu, or create one from Startup disk creator which is preinstalled in Ubuntu, you will just need to download the [Ubuntu image.](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)